# Bundle registering inside a vendor bundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I dont understand the bundle architecture correcty.
I created a bundle which parent is the FOSUserBundle. I want to use my created SHN/UserBundle inside other symfony2 installations.

Inside a target application i receive a

```
LogicException: Bundle "SHNUserBundle" extends bundle "FOSUserBundle", which is not registered.
```

I mean i extend the fosuserbundle which should be automatically registered because my SHN/UserBundle uses it?

Where is my thinking mistake?

**/src/SHN/UserBundle/composer.json:**

```
"name" : "SHN/UserBundle",
"description" : "Overwrites the FOS Userbundle with some futures",
"type" : "symfony-bundle",
"authors" : [{
    "name" : "Timo Linde",
    "email" : "timo.linde@shn-germany.de",
    "role" : "Developer"
}],
"keywords" : [
    "fos-userbundle extend"
],
"license" : [
    "proprietary"
],
"require" : {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3"
},
"autoload" : {
    "psr-0" : {
        "SHN\\UserBundle" : ""
    }
},
"target-dir" : "SHN/UserBundle",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed have a misunderstanding of the bundle inheritance model. It's not a Parent/Child relationship (yes, the name is very confusing...).

Imagine the case of templating (if you only override for templating, consider using [the `app/Resources` dir instead](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-etc)). When the template `FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig` is requested, instead of directly parsing the `@FOSUserBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig` file, it first looks if `@TheChildBundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig` exists and if so, it uses that one instead of the one that is located in the FOSUserBundle.

It's more of an override relationship.

This means that the FOSUserBundle still needs to be registered as well.

Comment: okay then i dont want to add the FOSUserBundle in the require part of my composer.json in my target application. Because it is already in the vendor folder from my vendor bundle SHN/Userbundle. How can i register it from that location? i get this exception:

Attempted to load class "FOSUserBundle" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle" in /var/www/shn/app/AppKernel.php line 21. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

Comment: Has anyone an idea about this?

Comment: Did you install the package using composer? If so, composer should do this for you

Comment: I install all packages using composer.
My Application composer.json have the require entrie:         "SHN/Userbundle": "dev-master"

But if i do not register the FOSUserBundle in my AppKernel it fails with 
LogicException: Bundle "SHNUserBundle" extends bundle "FOSUserBundle", which is not registered.